# How Do Inverse Relationships Work in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models/tables: `publisher` and `campaign.`

**Publisher**

```
id | name
```

**Campaign**

```
id | name | PubID
```

I created a relationship to get the Publisher's campaigns.

```
$this->hasMany(Campaign::class, 'PubID'); /* In Publisher Model */
```

I believe the above line will help me to retrieve relevant campaigns, but I'm confused about the inverse relationship.

As you can see, there is no key `campaign_id` inside the `publisher` table. Would the below relationship be enough for the inverse?

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Publisher'); /* In Campaign Model */
```

Can someone kindly guide me? I would appreciate it.

Comment: You also need to specify the foreign key name in the `belongsTo` part in the same way you do in the `hasMany` part.

Comment: @apokryfos as I said there is no foreign key of `campaign` table inside `publisher` table

Comment: There's no need for one. In fact you can only have a foreign key on both tables if the relationship is one-to-one (which is not the case here). The `PubID` in `Campaign` is enough to define both ends of the relationship

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is so called `one to many relationship`, which means one publisher has many campaigns. And the inverse is that a campaign belongs to a publisher. 
So in order to get all the campaigns for the publisher you use:

```
Publisher::find($id)->campaigns;
```

In order to get what is the publisher of the campaign, you use:

```
Campaign::find($id)->publisher;
```

You don't need `campaign_id` inside the publisher table, that is known by the `PubID` in your campaign table.

Comment: Alright, it's good explanation. But what about campaign model? Am I right in campaign model? Just want to confirm it. Thank you

Comment: @ScriptLover Yes, that's right. But keep in mind that whenever you use your custom name for the key such as `PubID` you will need to provide the name to the relationship, as you did with the hasMany, as the other guys are suggesting. A better naming convention is to use `publisher_id` in which case you won't need to manually add the foreign key column name.

Comment: Op does not explicitly say that a publisher can have many campaigns but NOT a campaign to be conducted by many publishers . So keeping in mind that a campaign can be conducted by many publishers, the answer by Ismoil at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517565/998537   holds weight.

Answer (score 1):

You have two models and adding two foreign id. It is a many to many working. You just need add pivot table with campain_id and publiser_id

It’s a perfect example of many-to-many relationship: one publisher can belong to several campains, and one campains can have multiple publisher.

**publishers**

ID | NAME

**campaigns**

ID | NAME

**campaign_publisher**

campain_id | publisher_id

The final table in the list – campaign_publisher is called a “pivot” table, as mentioned in the topic title.

So, option 1:

```
class Campaign extends Model
{
    /**
     * The products that belong to the shop.
     */
    public function publishers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Publisher');
    }
}
```

So, option 2:

```
class Publisher extends Model
{
    /**
     * The shops that belong to the product.
     */
    public function campaigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Campaign');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ,eed to specify the foreign key name in the belongsTo

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Publisher','PubID');
```

[Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)